# Why does dynamically created HTML5 video tags not honoring transforms on the iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html5-video

A video element that was appended will not honor transforms.

```
$parentDIV.append('<video id="myvideo" src="http://site.com//video.m4v"></video>');
```

This transform fails to work on the iPad (but works on the desktop)

```
$parentDIV.css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(100px)');
```

Comment: What browser you running on the iPad etc. Versus the one on the PC.

Comment: its safari on the ipad.  (are there other browsers for ipad?)
on the pc it works in both safari and chrome for pc.